# SQL count and avg

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I've got a problem with an SQL query.

The relation is

```
Journalist(JID(primary key), Name, Age, Salary, Chef -> Journalist.RID)
Article(AID(primary key), Title, Text)
Written(JID -> Journalist.JID, AID -> Article.AID, Date, Magazine)
```

Now I want to realize two querys:

1. The JID, the name of each Journalist who has written an article and is older than 62 and the amount of articles he has written.
2. The JID for each chef with more than 10 employees under him and the average age of his employees.

I have just begun to learn about SQL so I had a lot of difficulties figuring out the solution.. Now I've got this:

```
SELECT j.JID, j.Name
FROM Journalist j
WHERE j.Age > 61
```

Here is the amount of articles missing that each journalist has written. Do I have to use COUNT()?

For the second query I've got something like this:

```
SELECT j.JID, count(*)
FROM Journalist j
GROUP BY Chef
HAVING COUNT(*) > 9
```

Here I need the average of his employees. I thought that just using AVG() would give out the average of all employees.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not related to your question, but storing the date of birth is better than storing the age.  It's less likely to change over time.

Answer (score 1):

For the first query `Journalist who has written an article and is older than 62`, you have to modify your query a little bit, because you are not checking if the person has written an article or not.

```
SELECT j.JID, j.Name
FROM Journalist j
WHERE j.Age > 61
    AND j.JID IN (SELECT w.JID FROM written w)
```

To get the number of articles you have to use `COUNT` but first you have to form a relation to use `COUNT`. Try this

```
SELECT j.JID, J.Name, COUNT(a.AID) as [ArticlesWritten]
FROM Written w
    JOIN Article a ON a.AID = w.AID
    JOIN Journalist j ON w.JID = j.JID
GROUP BY j.JID, j.Name
```

For the second query about `chef with more than 10 employees under him` you need to provide us with more info about where is the employee information saved.

Comment: Good, but this relation is not needed : JOIN Article a ON a.AID = w.AID. Cheers.

Comment: @SRO Yes you are right. But I was trying to show how to `connect information between tables` as the OP seems to be new to this.

Answer (score 0):

In the first query you need also to join the Written table and group by JID and Name, it should be:

```
SELECT j.JID, j.Name, COUNT(*) AS articles
  FROM Journalist j INNER JOIN Written w ON j.JID=w.JID
 WHERE j.Age > 61
 GROUP BY j.JID, j.Name
```

in the second query ypu need to select the column you group by and also to add AVG:

```
SELECT Chef, count(*) AS empoyees, avg(Age) AS AverageAge
  FROM Journalist j
 GROUP BY Chef
HAVING COUNT(*) > 9
```

I hope this can help you

### Update

To avoid the join in the first query you cannot have the journalist's name but only the JID, the query then is:

```
SELECT JID, COUNT(*) AS WrittenArticles
  FROM Written
 WHERE JID IN (SELECT JID FROM Journalist WHERE j.Age > 61)
 GROUP BY JID
```

I can't figure out how list also the Journalist's name without a join.

Comment: thanks! can I do the first one without a JOIN? because my assignment says no JOIN operations.. to avoid this I used the IN operator

Comment: @teekay See my update. You can rewrite the first query without a JOIN, but to have the count of articles you need to query the Written table and you can't retrieve the journalist's name without join the Journalist table

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, you must of course use the Journalist table (since you need the name) AND the Written table (from wich you can tell who have written what). So you'll have to join both tables (inner join) and you'll have to GROUP in order to get a COUNT :

```
SELECT j.JID, j.NAME, count(*) as NumberOfArticleWritten
FROM   Journalist j
       inner join Written w on w.JID = j.JID
WHERE  j.Age >= 62
GROUP BY j.JID, j.NAME;
```

For the second question, the answer should look like this :

```
select j_chef.JID, 
       count(*) as NumberOfEmployees, 
       avg(j_employee.Age) as EmployeesAverageAge
from   Journalist j_chef
group by j_chef.JID
having count(*) > 10
```

Comment: Doesn't it have to be "FROM Journalist j_chef, Journalist j_employee"?

Answer (score 0):

first query

```
SELECT j.JID, j.Name,COUNT(*) as NumberOfArticles
FROM Journalist j left join Written W on j.JID=W.JID
group by j.jid,j.Name
HAVING j.Age > 61
```

second query: assuming JID of journalist table is stored in chief column i.e. self referencing table is used

```
SELECT Chief.JID, AVG(J.Age) 
FROM Journalist Chief left join Journalist j on J.RID=chief.JID 
GROUP BY Chief.JID HAVING COUNT(*)>10
```

Answer (score 0):

first query answer

```
SELECT j.JID, j.NAME, count(*) as NumberOfArticle
FROM   Journalist j
       inner join Written w on w.JID = j.JID
WHERE  j.Age >= 62
GROUP BY j.JID, j.NAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay thanks a lot!
I am supposed to avoid JOIN operations so after a little more work I came to the following solutions:

1. (The JID for each journalist who is older than 62 and the amount of articles he has written)

> ```
> SELECT j.JID, j.Name, count(*) AS WrittenArticles
> FROM Journalist j
> WHERE j.Age > 62
>       AND j.JID IN (SELECT w.JID FROM Written w)
> GROUP BY j.JID, j.Name
> ```

1. The JID for each chef with more than 10 employees and the average age of the employees he has. 
   I thought about something like that:

> ```
> SELECT c.JID, AVG(j.Age)
> FROM Journalist c, Journalist j
> WHERE 10 < (SELECT count(*) FROM Journalist GROUP BY Chef)
>       AND j.Chef = c.RID
> ```

Can I do it like that?